# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383

Tags: error, xml, error-log, system.log

I know this is a very general error but i need help getting it fixed.

I believe there is an extension with invalid XML and that's the cause of this error.

So if i have a syntax error somewhere in an extension's XML file, what would be the easiest way to scan through all my extensions? Is there an easy way to do this or am I going to have to go through them one by one?